# Using Hibernate in iReport. Could not parse mapping document

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using `Jasper iReport Designer 5.6.0` with `Hibernate`. I added my Class path which is related to my project but every time I try to test my Hibernate connection it comes up with the error like

> Could not parse mapping document from source../file.hbm.xml

But everything seems to work just fine in Eclipse. 
I'm using the 4.3.1.Final version of hibernate. is it the version i'm using that causes this kind of problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iReport ships and works with Hibernate version 3 (I'm not entirely sure how to check the exact version, quick google search suggests 3.0.5). That means, that your mapping file needs to be compliant with that version.

Or, you could pull the data from database using your java application and use that as a data source.

Comment: @Orionbelt If your flow could involve using java program you could keep using Hibernate4 there, and than just prepare POJOs for iReport to print which might be simpler than changing your mapping depending on what you have written. That's the only idea I have other than rewriting the mapping for Hibernate 3.